# How to fit a function to measurements with error?

Tags: julia

I am currently using Measurements.jl for error propagation and LsqFit.jl for fitting functions to data. Is there a simple way to fit a function to data with errors? It would be no problem to use an other package if that makes things easier.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This question is probably too broad for StackOverflow, consider posting on the Julia Discourse instead.

Comment: Have you tried if it "just works" to put input data with Measurements.jl uncertainty into LsqFit? If it does not work, what error message do you get?

Comment: I tried it. I get MethodError: no method matching Float64(::Measurement{Float64})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While in principle it should be possible to make these packages work together, the implementation of LsqFit.jl does not seem to play nicely with the `Measurement` type. However, if one writes a simple least-squares linear regression directly

```
# Generate test data, with noise
x = 1:10
y = 2x .+ 3
using Measurements
x_observed = (x .+ randn.()) .± 1
y_observed = (y .+ randn.()) .± 1

# Simple least-squares linear regression
# for an equation of the form y = a + bx
# using `\` for matrix division
linreg(x, y) = hcat(fill!(similar(x), 1), x) \ y
(a, b) = linreg(x_observed, y_observed)
```

then

```
julia> (a, b) = linreg(x_observed, y_observed)
2-element Vector{Measurement{Float64}}:
  3.9 ± 1.4
 1.84 ± 0.23
```

This ought to be able to work with either `x` uncertainties, `y` uncertainties, or both.

If you need a nonlinear least-squares fit, it should also be possible to extend the above approach to nonlinear least squares --  though for the latter it may be easier to just find where the incompatibility is in LsqFit.jl and make a PR.

Comment: Thanks alot! I'll use that for my linear regression problem. If I figure out a way to make it work with lsqFit I'll make a PR.